# How to get Django QuerySet 'exclude' to work right?

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have a database that contains schemas for skus, kits, kit_contents, and checklists.  Here is a query for "Give me all the SKUs defined for kitcontent records defined for kit records defined in checklist 1":

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.* FROM skus s
JOIN kit_contents kc ON kc.sku_id = s.id
JOIN kits k          ON k.id = kc.kit_id
JOIN checklists c    ON k.checklist_id = 1;
```

I'm using Django, and I mostly really like the ORM because I can express that query by:

```
skus = SKU.objects.filter(kitcontent__kit__checklist_id=1).distinct()
```

which is such a slick way to navigate all those foreign keys.  Django's ORM produces basically the same as the SQL written above.  The trouble is that it's not clear to me how to get all the SKUs *not* defined for checklist 1.  In the SQL query above, I'd do this by replacing the "=" with "!=".  But Django's models don't have a not equals operator.  You're supposed to use the exclude() method, which one might guess would look like this:

```
skus = SKU.objects.filter().exclude(kitcontent__kit__checklist_id=1).distinct()
```

but Django produces this query, which isn't the same thing:

```
SELECT distinct s.*  FROM skus s 
WHERE NOT ((skus.id IN 
    (SELECT kc.sku_id FROM kit_contents kc 
    INNER JOIN kits k ON (kc.kit_id = k.id) 
    WHERE (k.checklist_id = 1  AND kc.sku_id IS NOT NULL)) 
AND skus.id IS NOT NULL))
```

(I've cleaned up the query for easier reading and comparison.)

I'm a beginner to the Django ORM, and I'd like to use it when possible.  Is there a way to get what I want here?

EDIT:

karthikr gave an answer that doesn't work for the same reason the original ORM .exclude() solution doesn't work: a SKU can be in kit_contents in kits that exist on *both* checklist_id=1 and checklist_id=2.  Using the by-hand query I opened my post with, using "checklist_id = 1" produces 34 results, using "checklist_id = 2" produces 53 results, and the following query produces 26 results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.* FROM skus s
JOIN kit_contents kc ON kc.sku_id = s.id
JOIN kits k          ON k.id = kc.kit_id
JOIN checklists c    ON k.checklist_id = 1
JOIN kit_contents kc2 ON kc2.sku_id = s.id
JOIN kits k2          ON k2.id = kc2.kit_id
JOIN checklists c2    ON k2.checklist_id = 2;
```

I think this is one reason why people don't seem to find the .exclude() solution a reasonable replacement for some kind of not_equals filter -- the latter allows you to say, succinctly, exactly what you mean.  Presumably the former could also allow the query to be expressed, but I increasingly despair of such a solution being simple.

Comment: Side note: you don't need the extra call to `filter()`, you can just do `SKU.objects.exclude(...)`

Comment: Do you want all skus not related to checklist 1, or all skus related to checklists other than 1? Or does "not defined for checklist 1" mean something else entirely?

Comment: All skus related to checklists other than 1.  The difficulty seems to be that they may _also_ be related to 1, but I don't want to know about them in their 1-related senses.  The join syntax in my original SQL query expresses this distinction (blah blah blah join checklists c where k.checklists.id != 1) but I can't make the .exclude do so.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this - get all the objects for checklist 1, and exclude it from the complete list.

```
sku_ids = skus.values_list('pk', flat=True)
non_checklist_1 = SKU.objects.exclude(pk__in=sku_ids).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; but see my edit for why it doesn't work.